# What is the Keycode for % sign?

Tags: c#, .net

I am using C#.Net. I have textbox which allow only number, decimal and percentage(%) sign. I have the keycode for all number and decimal, but what is the "%" sign's keycode?

How can I check the `keydown` event for %?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Something like this:

```
private void yourControl_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
   if((e.KeyCode == Keys.D5) && e.Shift)
   {
      // User pressed '%' ...
   }
}
```

or

```
private void yourControl_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    switch(e.KeyCode)
    {
        //... 
        case Keys.D5:
            if(e.Shift)
            {
                // Handle '%'
            }
            else
            {
                // Handle '5'
            }
            break;
        // ...
    }
}
```

You want to check that the key being pressed is the 5 key, and that it has been modified by pressing the shift key.

Comment: how can i check with 

switch (e.KeyCode)
            {
                case Keys.Add:   -- I need percentage sign to check

Comment: can you please help me out in the case of if i compare in switch case

Comment: what if the % sign isn't on shift+5? (e.g. french keyboard layout)

Comment: @d0k: Interesting point.  Not sure how you'd handle it then :|

Comment: btw, in russian % is shift+5 too. it's pity then in french not. it would be nice # and % to be always on the same button

Comment: Thanks lot.. it's working fine in English keyboard.. thanks for ur answer.

Comment: I prefer the switch statement because it let user to select number key or percentage key.

Answer (score 3):

Ascii code for "%" is 37, and in unicode &#37.

Comment: and KeyEventArgs.KeyValue is 53

Answer (score 0):

Here is a textbox restricting pattern:

```
    private void AmountPaidTextBox_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        switch ((byte)e.KeyChar)
        {
            case 48:
            case 49:
            case 50:
            case 51:
            case 52:
            case 53:
            case 54:
            case 55:
            case 56:
            case 57:
            case 58:
            case 59:
            case 46:
            case 35:

                //This is a valid character
                e.Handled = false;
                break;
            default:
                //This is an invalid character
                e.Handled = true;
                break;

        }
    }
```

Comment: The original did not have case 35 in it, as I only allow numbers and decimals.

Comment: Oops, that should be case 37, per the ASCII chart (http://www.unitechnical.info/Products/ASCII-Chart.jpg). Ouch!